# Laravel Collection Returns Inconsistant Results

Tags: php, laravel-5, collections

I have a collection that will switch between responding as an `array` or as an `object` seemingly at random. What would cause that to happen?

```
$events = Event::all();

$events = $events->map(function ($event) use ($request) {
    $reducedEventName   = Helper::alphaNum($event->name);
    $reducedRequestName = Helper::alphaNum($request->name);
    $distance           = levenshtein($reducedEventName, $reducedRequestName);

    return [
        'name'     => $event->name,
        'url'      => route('event.view', ['slug' => $event->slug]),
        'distance' => $distance,
    ];
})
->filter(function ($event) {
    return $event['distance'] <= Helper::threshold($event['name']);
})
->take(3)
->sortBy('distance');

return $events->toArray();
```

This method is called via XHR, so I want the raw `JSON` response. Sometimes it looks like this ():

```
[{
  "name": "Taylor Swift - Reputation - Release",
  "url": "http:\/\/localhost\/e\/lgKejoPSg",
  "distance": 22
}, {
  "name": "Wiz Khalifa \"Laugh now, fly later\"",
  "url": "http:\/\/localhost\/e\/DdLnFD3Qf",
  "distance": 24
}]
```

And sometimes it looks like this ():

```
{
  "1": {
    "name": "Wiz Khalifa \"Laugh now, fly later\"",
    "url": "http:\/\/localhost\/e\/DdLnFD3Qf",
    "distance": 18
  },
  "0": {
    "name": "Taylor Swift - Reputation - Release",
    "url": "http:\/\/localhost\/e\/lgKejoPSg",
    "distance": 23
  }
}
```

---

`Laravel 5.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resorting the results tries to preserve the original keys, so I needed to discard the original keys:

```
return array_values($events->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

As to your question, I am not sure what could cause that to happen as the sortBy() method states it returns a collection. Do you return that exact $events as is to your blade? If so that could be inconsistency on the browser deciding how to handle the collection that is sent back to it. You could always use ->toArray() at the end of your query to ensure that it always returns an array, or ->toJson() if you don't want to do anything else with it.

Comment: Yes, I return them as is. No transformation going on. I did try `toArray()` and it doesn't correct the behavior. Sometimes it's an array, sometimes an object. `toJson()` does the same.

Comment: I've also tested the request/response in different browsers as well as in Paw (a REST API tool) and the response seems to be the fault of the server.

Comment: This is an interesting one then. If toArray() doesn't throw an error then it should be a collection instance and should be able to be morphed into a json string. Looking into the collection class there is also the jsonSerialize() method, which says it converts the object into something JSON serializable. I wonder if that might help.